# Dart: run two methods at the same time and wait for them to finish

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I'm playing around with dart/flutter and I can't work out how to run two functions at the SAME time and wait for them to finish.

Apparently, I should use isolate.spawn but can't get anything to work, for instance:

```
t1(dynamic t) {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
}

t2(dynamic t) {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
}

main() async {
  Future f1 = Isolate.spawn(getThing, null);
  Future f2 =  Isolate.spawn(getThing1, null);
  Future.wait([f1,f2]);
}
```

Whilst the two functions run, the call to Future.wait doesn't wait for them to finish.

Then there's the problem of how do I deal with any return values from the functions.

Anyone? 
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet does not work because
[Isolate.spawn](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawn.html) returns a future which
will complete with an `Isolate` instance if the spawning succeeded, not when the entry point, in this case `t1` and `t2`, return.

To deal with the return values of the spawned functions you may use a [`ReceivePort`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html). For example:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

t1(port) {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 3));
  port.send(["t1", 1]);
}

t2(port) {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 6));
  port.send(["t2", 2]);
}

main() async {
  var receivePort = new ReceivePort();

  Isolate.spawn(t1, receivePort.sendPort);
  Isolate.spawn(t2, receivePort.sendPort);

  await for (var retMsg in receivePort) {
    print("res: $retMsg");

    if (retMsg[0] == "t2") {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find [`package:isolate`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/isolate) useful here.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:isolate/isolate.dart';

t1(dynamic t) {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
}

t2(dynamic t) {
  sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
}

void main() async {
  var isolate1 = await IsolateRunner.spawn();
  var isolate2 = await IsolateRunner.spawn();
  var f1 = isolate1.run(t1, null);
  var f2 = isolate2.run(t2, null);
  await Future.wait([f1, f2]);
  await Future.wait([isolate1.close(), isolate2.close()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to add await, then you can store the values in a variable and you will get a simple list of answers.

```
void bigFunction() async {
  final v1 = customWait(10);
  final v2 = customWait(5);
  final value = await Future.wait([v1, v2]);
  print(value);
}

Future<int> customWait(int time) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: time));
  return time + 10;
}
```